# How to fix Unicode characters not rendering in .NET Graphics DrawString?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, graphics, fonts

I am using Graphics.DrawString to render a string with some Unicode symbols in it (if it matters, the symbols are the MICR transit and on-us symbols, U+2446 and U+2448). The font that's being used is created with the GenericMonospace font family.

The code runs fine and draws the symbols with no issues when running on my local development machine in debug mode. However, when this runs on the QA machine, it runs without error but draws the blank boxes instead of the Unicode symbols.

Is this something that's fixable in code (e.g. using a specific font/typeface, maybe Courier New, rather than the GenericMonospace family)? Or is this, as I suspect, an issue that needs to be fixed by installing something extra on the QA machine (if so, what)? Or is there something else I'm missing, like build settings or Windows features that are different?

Here is code that works great on my local but prints boxes on the QA machine:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(400, 400);
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);

gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 400, 400);

string str1 = String.Format(
    "{0} {1} {2} {3}", 
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(9286), 
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(9287), 
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(9288), 
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(9289));

try
{
    Font f1 = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12);
    gr.DrawString(str1, f1, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, 10));
}
catch (Exception) { }

// image has MICR symbols on local but boxes on QA machine
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: Note: I'd prefer not to install and use some MICR-specific font, though I am aware that's an option. This question is about making the Unicode characters show up in a "standard" font/typeface like Arial, Courier, Times New Roman, etc. Prefer monospace and/or fixed-width solutions. GenericMonospace worked on my local!

Comment: This is probably a missing-font issue, so changing to a more widely installed font may fix it. Courier New is a good bet. You should be able to check this with a very simple Windows Forms app which just displays the affected string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tried Courier New and a few others (Arial, Times New Roman, etc.) and it looks like all of them print boxes rather than the symbols. I agree that it seems like the QA machine is missing Unicode support for some reason.

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you put your comment in an answer along with anything you might know about ensuring Courier New has Unicode support on Windows Server 2012 (if anything), I'll gladly accept. Since the forms app showed no matches in any font/typeface I tried, even in notepad, the answer is just to install. I don't know how but I guess that's a Server Fault question now.